# unexpected tIDENTIFIER with keyword argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to create a method with a keyword argument, but I'm having some trouble. At the moment I have:

```
my_method(option_key:, location, options = {})
```

but I get the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER (SyntaxError)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the keyword args to the last position of the arguments list:

```
def my_method(location, options = {}, option_key:) 
end
```

Comment: Yup thanks, I'll accept when I'm allowed